# Questions about the nextTuple method in the Spout of Storm stream processing

Tags: stream, apache-storm

I am developing some data analysis algorithms on top of Storm and have some questions about the internal design of Storm. I want to simulate a sensor data yielding and processing in Storm, and therefore I use Spout to push sensor data into the succeeding bolts at a constant time interval via setting a sleep method in nextTuple method of Spout. But from the experiment results, it appeared that spout didn't push data at the specified rate. In the experiment, there was no bottleneck bolt in the system.

Then I checked some material about the ack and nextTuple methods of Storm. Now my doubt is if the nextTuple method is called only when the previous tuples are fully processed and acked in the ack method?

If this is true, does it means that I cannot set a fixed time interval to emit data?

Thx a lot!

Comment: I like this question, but you may have better luck asking it on the storm-users mailing list. However, I see my answer below for some info I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that you should not expect Storm to make any real-time guarantees, including in your case the rate of tuple processing. You can certainly write a spout that only emits tuples on some time schedule, but Storm can't really guarantee that it will always call on the spout as often as you would like.

Note that nextTuple should be called whenever there is room available for more pending tuples in the topology. If the topology has free capacity, I would expect Storm to try to fill it up if it can with whatever it can get.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use-case, and the way I accomplished it is by using  `TICK_TUPLE`

```
Config tickConfig = new Config();                                       
tickConfig.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 15);
...
...
builder.setBolt("storage_bolt", new S3Bolt(), 4).fieldsGrouping("shuffle_bolt", new Fields("hash")).addConfigurations(tickConfig);
```

Then in my `storage_bolt` (note it's written in `python`, but you will get an idea) i check if message is `tick_tuple` if it is then execute my code:

```
def process(self, tup): 
    if tup.stream == '__tick':                                              
        # Your logic that need to be executed every 15 seconds,
        # or what ever you specified in tickConfig.
        # NOTE: the maximum time is 600 s.                                            
        storm.ack(tup)                                                      
        return
```